# Meteor publish: admin can view all data, user only his data

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a collection (Collection2 package):

```
tickets = new Mongo.Collection("tickets");
```

I would like to show, through the template, ALL USER tickets if admin is logged in, else only current user tickets.

My server code (meteor-rules package) :

```
Meteor.publish('tickets', function(){
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['admin'])){
        return tickets.find({},{sort:{deadline: 1}});
    }else{
        return tickets.find({_id: this.userId}, {sort:{deadline: 1}});
    }
});
```

My client code:

```
Template.dashboard.helpers({
  tickets: function () {
    Meteor.subscribe('tickets');
  });
```

Nothing happened on template...what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template helper must return actual data, but in your code you don't return anything, just subscribe to your tickets.

```
Template.dashboard.helpers({
  tickets: function () {
    // return a cursor fetching all tickets that were pushed to the client
    // thanks to the subscription
    return tickets.find();
  }
});
```

Depending on your needs, you may want to use `iron:router` to display your dashboard only when the subscription is ready, or else it will be displayed unpopulated at first.

Comment: Thanks @saimeunt, but with autopublish installed now return all the tickets without separate admin ticket with users ticket. And if I remove autopublish all disappear... :-(

Comment: Try debugging by `console.log`ing in the publish function the resultsets of your cursors : `console.log(tickets.find(...).fetch());`

Comment: Nothing appeared... I take a look here: http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Understanding_Meteor_Publish_and_Subscribe and it seems that isn't necessary return data if data was returned inside the publish method..

Comment: It works now! My query error {_id:this.userId} instead of {user:this.userId} in publication. Also I added return tickets.find() as you suggested me @saimeunt.

Comment: Also, FYI, I don't think sorting in the publication does anything.  It works only in the helper.